# How to create an Outlook rule that copies messages to a folders AFTER the message has been received and categorized?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I am looking for a way make a copy of Outlook 2007 messages in a folder automatically. Boss man wants someone to be able to file emails but not get all of his email. I can get him to do simple things, like assign a filing category to his emails. I can create a rule that will copy the message if it comes in with that category marked, but that won't be the case. He will read the message THEN mark it filing. Is there any way to make the rule copy these messages automatically or will I have to find a way to have him manually run the rule to make that happen? In the alternative, is there a way to make "Copy to Folder" a shortcut somewhere for him to just copy this stuff over? Kicker is he doesn't want the emails actually moved out of his inbox, just copied.

Comment: Outlook 2010 has easy ways of doing this, but that may not be a solution for you.